# Changing tags in a chatroom shows an error page

Tags: bug, chat

When I try to add tags to a chatroom, I get directed to an error page. ([this one](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/error?aspxerrorpath=/rooms/save)).

I tried figuring out why this happens, and when I add a tag without clicking on the list of tags that show up, I end up on that page. If I for an instance try to add the python tag, just writing it shows the error page. Writing python and clicking on it in the list that shows up allows me to edit it successfully.

Is this a bug or is it intended?

## Reproduction

I already mentioned this above, but anyways:

- Edit a room you own
- Add a tag by writing (e.g. `python`) -> Error page
- Add a tag by writing and then clicking on the name -> saves correctly